# Resize an image using an image cropper in Umbraco 7.6

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

**Update:** I'll make some crops for the Umbraco's image cropper *(`Umbraco.ImageCropper`)* in Umbraco 7.6. The users uploads images over the 4MB *(some images are over the 7MB)*. Now I'll <strike>crop</strike> resize this images to improve page speed.

I've seen that some of the images are taken in landscape and others in portrait. For a image gallery I'll have the original height and width ratio but with a max width of 500 pixels with a variable height.

I've tried to place the height empty and place to zero but both gives me an error:

[image]

I can only make crops with a fixed width and height. Now my questions are:

1. Could I give the crop a variable height dependent on the original size of the image?
2. Could I just resize the image to a fixed width?

Comment: For now I've found a fall back to do this: Here is my code: `<img src="@img.Url?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=500" />` _(`img` type of `Image` is the variable with the current image)_. I haven't created a new crop for that.

Comment: I have a similar requirement at the moment and have had to resort to the same solution as you. I kind of understand why you cannot do it and that is because there would actually be no crop area to define since the image will not be cropped at all, simply resized. Have you tried asking on the Umbraco forums?

Comment: @ProNotion: Yes, I've asked it also there: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/89137-crop-images-with-a-variable-height-dependent-on-the-original-height-of-the-image-using-an-image-cutter